# Открытие вкладки браузера в то же окне на QWebEngineView. Не передаётся referrer

Tags: python, pyqt5, qwebengine

Есть код:

```py
class WebEnginePage(QWebEnginePage):

    def createWindow(self, _type):
        page = WebEnginePage(self)
        page.urlChanged.connect(self.on_url_changed)
        return page

    @pyqtSlot(QUrl)
    def on_url_changed(self, url):
        page = self.sender()
        self.setUrl(url)
        page.deleteLater()

class MainWindow(QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super(MainWindow, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        self.browser = QWebEngineView()
        page = WebEnginePage(self.browser)
        self.browser.setPage(page)
        self.browser.setUrl(QUrl("http://yandex.ru"))
```

При переходе по любому сайту из выдачи яндекса или же просто при переходе по ссылке с target="_blank" ... В программе страница открывается в том же окне, однако счётчики видят такой переход не корректно без referrer. Видится как прямой заход. Тестировал со своих сайтов так же .. Если в обычном браузере перехожу с target="_blank" то referrer виден перехода и отображается сайт с которого был переход. Если перехожу с программы с кодом, показаном выше то идёт как прямой заход. Помогите разобраться. Спасибо!

Comment: Выводится всё это дело в self.setCentralWidget(self.browser).... Попробовал подставить за место QWebEngineView - QWebEnginePage .. но тогда бъёт ошибку на self.browser.setPage(page) ...Асинхронные запросы нет не учитываю ... а как сделать дополнительную обвязку? подскажите пожалуйста.По поводу  завершения первого запроса .. да, у меня нет для этого заглушки. А можете показать как на моём коде корректно внести коррективы? Спасибо!

Comment: Я вижу, что Вы использовали готовый код из другого ответа. К, сожалению, не все ответы 100% верны. Насчёт асинхронности QWebEngine посмотрите, например, [здесь](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53221137/9921853) и [здесь](https://stackoverflow.com/a/37755811/9921853). Напрямую помочь не смогу - с QWebEngine не работал. Просто зацепился глаз за несоответствие конструктора и инициализации. А дальше погуглил по обоим классам

Comment: @yong Вы пишете `однако счётчики видят такой переход не корректно без referrer.` 
Напишите пожалуйста поподробнее, о каких счётчиках идет речь.
Как вы определяете `не корректно без referrer` или `корректно с referrer`.
Приведите пожалуйста пример демонстрирующий проблему.

Comment: Отзываю свои комментарии про инициализацию класса `WebEnginePage` - глупость сморозил. Но вот насчет асинхронности работы пакета - это Вам надо учитывать.

Comment: S. Nick, через google analytics ... захожу на сайт с обычного браузера и так